# responsive dynamic html

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, responsive-design

How can I make a html element to change if the media width is lower than, let's say 726px ?

For example I have one image and I want to change it with another if the media width is lower than 726px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to bundle your low-resolution styles in a separate css file that you can activate by including the following link in you html head section:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width:726px)" href="your-low-res-styles.css" title="norrowscreen" />
```

Regarding you question: "Is there a way to change the html...":
Include a matchMedia listener in you code:

```
if (window.matchMedia !== undefined) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 726px)");
    mq.addListener(onWidthChange);
    onWidthChange(mq);
}
function onWidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
        $("#img0").attr("src", url1);
    } else {
        $("#img0").attr("src", url2);
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the css to take effect up until `726px`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 726px) {
   background-image: url(image-med.png);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 727px) {
   background-image: url(image-big.png)
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but I want to use image in <img> tag in html insted of background-image. Is there a way to change the html code depending of the media width, like in css ?

Comment: you could use a small jquery plugin: https://github.com/teleject/hisrc  and then set your `img` tag to: `<img src="200x100.png" data-1x="400x200.png" data-2x="800x400.png">`

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 726px){
#div{  background-image: url(image-1.png)}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 727px){
#div{  background-image: url(image-2.png)}
}
```

Comment: That's nice, but I want to use image in <img> tag in html insted of background-image. Is there a way to change the html code depending of the media width, like in css ?